# Combining observations with overlapping dates

Tags: r, date, overlap

Each observations in my dataframe contains a different "before date" and "after date instance".  The problem is some dates overlap for each ID.  For instance, in the table below, ID's 1 and 4 contain overlapping date values.

```
ID  before date after date
1   10/1/1996   12/1/1996
1   1/1/1998    9/30/2003
1   1/1/2000    12/31/2004
2   1/1/2001    3/31/2006
3   1/1/2001    9/30/2006
4   1/1/2001    9/30/2005
4   10/1/2004   12/30/2004
4   10/3/2004   11/28/2004
```

I am trying to get something like this:

```
ID  before date after date
1   10/1/1996   12/1/1996
1   1/1/1998    12/31/2004
2   1/1/2001    3/31/2006
3   1/1/2001    9/30/2006
4   1/1/2001    9/30/2005
```

Basically, I would like to replace any overlapping date values with the date range of the values with the overlap, leave the non-overlapping values alone, and delete any unnecessary rows.  Not sure how to go about doing this

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you should convert your string dates into `Date`-classed values, which will make comparison possible. Here's how I've defined and coerced your data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4), before.date=c('10/1/1996','1/1/1998','1/1/2000','1/1/2001','1/1/2001','1/1/2001','10/1/2004','10/3/2004'), after.date=c('12/1/1996','9/30/2003','12/31/2004','3/31/2006','9/30/2006','9/30/2005','12/30/2004','11/28/2004') );
dcis <- grep('date$',names(df));
df[dcis] <- lapply(df[dcis],as.Date,'%m/%d/%Y');
df;
##   ID before.date after.date
## 1  1  1996-10-01 1996-12-01
## 2  1  1998-01-01 2003-09-30
## 3  1  2000-01-01 2004-12-31
## 4  2  2001-01-01 2006-03-31
## 5  3  2001-01-01 2006-09-30
## 6  4  2001-01-01 2005-09-30
## 7  4  2004-10-01 2004-12-30
## 8  4  2004-10-03 2004-11-28
```

Now, my solution involves computing an "overlapping grouping" vector which I've called `og`. It makes the assumption that the input `df` is ordered by `ID` and then `before.date`, which it is in your example data. If not, this could be achieved by `df[order(df$ID,df$before.date),]`. Here's how I compute `og`:

```
cummax.Date <- function(x) as.Date(cummax(as.integer(x)),'1970-01-01');
og <- with(df,c(0,cumsum(!(ID[-length(ID)]==ID[-1] & ave(after.date,ID,FUN=cummax)[-length(after.date)]>before.date[-1]))));
og;
## [1] 0 1 1 2 3 4 4 4
```

Unfortunately, the base R `cummax()` function doesn't work on `Date`-classed objects, so I had to write a `cummax.Date()` shim. I'll explain the need for the `ave()` and `cummax()` business at the end of the post.

As you can see, the above computation lags the RHS of each of the two vectorized comparisons by excluding the first element via `[-1]`. This allows us to compare a record's `ID` for equality with the following record's `ID`, and also compare if its `after.date` is after the `before.date` of the following record. The resulting logical vectors are ANDed (`&`) together. The negation of that logical vector then represents adjacent pairs of records that do *not* overlap, and thus we can `cumsum()` the result (and prepend zero, as the first record must start with zero) to get our grouping vector.

Finally, for the final piece of the solution, I've used `by()` to work with each overlapping group independently:

```
do.call(rbind,by(df,og,function(g) transform(g[1,],after.date=max(g$after.date))));
##   ID before.date after.date
## 0  1  1996-10-01 1996-12-01
## 1  1  1998-01-01 2004-12-31
## 2  2  2001-01-01 2006-03-31
## 3  3  2001-01-01 2006-09-30
## 4  4  2001-01-01 2005-09-30
```

Since all records in a group must have the same `ID`, and we've made the assumption that records are ordered by `before.date` (after being ordered by `ID`, which is no longer relevant), we can get the correct `ID` and `before.date` values from the first record in the group. That's why I started with `g[1,]`. Then we just need to get the greatest `after.date` from the group via `max(g$after.date)`, and overwrite the first record's `after.date` with that, which I've done with `transform()`.

A word about performance: The assumption about ordering aids performance, because it allows us to simply compare each record against the immediately following record via lagged vectorized comparisons, rather than comparing every record in a group with every other record.

Now, for the `ave()` and `cummax()` business. I realized after writing the initial version of my answer that there was a flaw in my solution, which happens to not be exposed by your example data. Say there are three records in a group. If the first record has a range that overlaps with *both* of the following two records, and then the middle record does *not* overlap with the third record, then my (original) code would fail to identify that the third record is part of the same overlapping group of the previous two records.

The solution is to not simply use the `after.date` of the current record when comparing against the following record, but instead use the cumulative maximum `after.date` within the group. If any earlier record sprawled completely beyond its immediately following record, then it obviously overlapped with that record, and its `after.date` is what's important in considering overlapping groups for subsequent records.

Here's a demonstration of input data that requires this fix, using your `df` as a base:

```
df2 <- df;
df2[7,'after.date'] <- '2004-10-02';
df2;
##   ID before.date after.date
## 1  1  1996-10-01 1996-12-01
## 2  1  1998-01-01 2003-09-30
## 3  1  2000-01-01 2004-12-31
## 4  2  2001-01-01 2006-03-31
## 5  3  2001-01-01 2006-09-30
## 6  4  2001-01-01 2005-09-30
## 7  4  2004-10-01 2004-10-02
## 8  4  2004-10-03 2004-11-28
```

Now record 6 overlaps with both records 7 and 8, but record 7 does not overlap with record 8. The solution still works:

```
cummax.Date <- function(x) as.Date(cummax(as.integer(x)),'1970-01-01');
og <- with(df2,c(0,cumsum(!(ID[-length(ID)]==ID[-1] & ave(after.date,ID,FUN=cummax)[-length(after.date)]>before.date[-1]))));
og;
## [1] 0 1 1 2 3 4 4 4
do.call(rbind,by(df2,og,function(g) transform(g[1,],after.date=max(g$after.date))));
##   ID before.date after.date
## 0  1  1996-10-01 1996-12-01
## 1  1  1998-01-01 2004-12-31
## 2  2  2001-01-01 2006-03-31
## 3  3  2001-01-01 2006-09-30
## 4  4  2001-01-01 2005-09-30
```

Here's a proof that the `og` calculation would be wrong without the `ave()`/`cummax()` fix:

```
og <- with(df2,c(0,cumsum(!(ID[-length(ID)]==ID[-1] & after.date[-length(after.date)]>before.date[-1]))));
og;
## [1] 0 1 1 2 3 4 4 5
```

---

Minor adjustment to the solution, to overwrite `after.date` in advance of the `og` computation, and avoid the `max()` call (makes more sense if you're planning on overwriting the original `df` with the new aggregation):

```
cummax.Date <- function(x) as.Date(cummax(as.integer(x)),'1970-01-01');
df$after.date <- ave(df$after.date,df$ID,FUN=cummax);
df;
##   ID before.date after.date
## 1  1  1996-10-01 1996-12-01
## 2  1  1998-01-01 2003-09-30
## 3  1  2000-01-01 2004-12-31
## 4  2  2001-01-01 2006-03-31
## 5  3  2001-01-01 2006-09-30
## 6  4  2001-01-01 2005-09-30
## 7  4  2004-10-01 2005-09-30
## 8  4  2004-10-03 2005-09-30
og <- with(df,c(0,cumsum(!(ID[-length(ID)]==ID[-1] & after.date[-length(after.date)]>before.date[-1]))));
og;
## [1] 0 1 1 2 3 4 4 4
df <- do.call(rbind,by(df,og,function(g) transform(g[1,],after.date=g$after.date[nrow(g)])));
df;
##   ID before.date after.date
## 0  1  1996-10-01 1996-12-01
## 1  1  1998-01-01 2004-12-31
## 2  2  2001-01-01 2006-03-31
## 3  3  2001-01-01 2006-09-30
## 4  4  2001-01-01 2005-09-30
```

Comment: Hi, bgoldst.  Thanks so much for this answer.  However, I got a warning that said "NAs introduced by coercion".  I looked at my df and only the first row is appearing

Comment: Hi michael. Can you provide me your real data? Either by editing it into your question, or posting it to dropbox, preferably the output of `dput()`. Thanks!